# CSS Weirdness on both Main and Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

CSS for both the Main and Meta sites seems to have changed sometime in the last 24 hours.  Links are now confusing as hell.  There's a baffling mixture of light red, dark red, and blue coloring all being used for visited/unvisited, depending on which section of the page you're looking at.  The main content of the page, other areas of the main content, and the different sections of the sidebar all seem to have different rules on which color means visited and which color means unvisited.

[User profile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1027/keen) layout is all borked too.

On Meta when I use my mod-power to view deleted comments inline, the CSS makes them unreadable.

Comment: The last time around, it was down to programmer error. I recall being quite excited that maybe we were getting the new user card, then disappointed again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's presumably the same thing that caused this question on Meta.SE months ago.

[Problems with SF&F and Seasoned Advice SE CSS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259185/problems-with-sff-and-seasoned-advice-se-css/259186#259186)

I've asked that the status-completed tag be removed so that it becomes active again and I've commented on the answer linked to bring attention to it.

It seems to be an issue on all sites that don't have the CSS update.

As an Epilogue, I've been told that, rather than asking for the tag to be removed, a new topic should be created.

> Can we un-status-completed this? It's broken again. – Catija 30 mins ago   declined - If it's broken again, then please create a new bug report. You can reference this one if you'd like.

So, I have done this, here:

[SFF and Mi Yodeya (and other sites without CSS update) are experiencing odd link colors & Broken User Profile pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267265/sff-and-mi-yodeya-are-experiencing-odd-link-colors)

Comment: What is surprising to me is that this has now occurred [twice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259185/problems-with-sff-and-seasoned-advice-se-css/259186#259186). I don't know how SE tests, but I would imagine that, after the first time, automated tests would be created to make sure this could not occur a second time ("mistake-proofing"). Is this not the case?

Comment: @Wikis Technically this is the third time. If I had to guess, they didn't bother with making tests for it because the code that is effected is going the way of the dodo within the next month. And was likely supposed to be gone already.